# [airflow]hive_hook: can not connect to hive metastore

Tags: airflow

I installed it and run a HivePartitionSensor to test hive meta store connection.It throw a exception than tell me can not connect to hive meta store

thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not connect to ...

,but I'm sure the host and port is right.I find that the port return from mysql is long type such as 9083L,so I change the source code in hive_hooks.py from

```
socket = TSocket.TSocket(ms.host, ms.port)
```

to

```
socket = TSocket.TSocket(ms.host, int(ms.port))
```

just cast ms.port to int,it works!
Does anyone came across this problem before?

Env:python2.7,airflow:v1-8-stable,mysql 5.7

Comment: the exception throw from :"airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.py", line 487, in check_for_partition self.metastore._oprot.trans.open()